# Javascript function resize window height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid thats a total of 1440px in height and it has a mixture of images and panels of text. The text is giving me real problems and media queries cant solve this issue. I want to make a function that resizes the whole div by half height and half width so it looks like its responsive. e.g the content shrinks. Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $gridRow = $('.grid-row');
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $gridRow.height($gridRow.width() / 2);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: added..my bad so tired..

Comment: The row will not respect the resize if their elements stand with their original width and height. Try to set the resize for all the row DOM hierarchy (images, divs, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *(I did the example without bootstrap)*:

https://jsfiddle.net/dkzmgbee/

```
var $gridRow = $('.example');

function resizeHeight () {
  var cw = $gridRow.width() / 2;
  $gridRow.css({'height':cw+'px'});
}  

$(window).resize(resizeHeight);
resizeHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it i have your question right.  But instead of going into media query hell try,

flowtype.js
https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS?files=1

...If its just a case of the text not resizing to the nth degree and you are depending on users using javascript.

There are a few other libraries that do something similar, (or hell do it yourself if you must)

Be careful not to overcomplicate this... i don't know your issue exactly but is it more simple than you think it is?  is this a css problem or something that javascript needs to deal with?  ( i only ask as you mentioned your tired )